# Как можно записать данное условие с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть условие: Год будет считается високосным если он кратен 5, но из тех что кратны 100 високосными будут только те, что кратны 500. Например 200, 300, 400 - невисокосный, 500 - високосный. Всего 1000 лет

Условия кратности у меня:

```js
// к-ство високосных лет кратных 5
function firstCountYears() {
  let maxYear = 1000;
  let counter = 0;
  while (maxYear >= 5) {
    counter++;
    maxYear = maxYear - 5;
  }
  return counter;
}
let multipleOfFive = firstCountYears();


// к-ство високосных лет кратных 100
function secondCountYears() {
  let maxYear = 1000;
  let counter = 0;
  while (maxYear >= 100) {
    counter++;
    maxYear = maxYear - 100;
  }
  return counter;
}
let multipleOfHundred = secondCountYears();


// к-ство високосных лет кратных 500
function thirdCountYears() {
  let maxYear = 1000;
  let counter = 0;
  while (maxYear >= 500) {
    counter++;
    maxYear = maxYear - 500;
  }
  return counter;
}
let multipleOfFiveHundred = thirdCountYears();
```

Как можно записать данное условие на JS? Буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: А можно приложить примеры годов, если кратные 5 я могу понять, а что считается кратное 100? Есть ли пример своих попыток, или может математическая формула?

Comment: Из тех годов, что кратные 5, те которые кратные 100 - это 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000. Из них кратными будут только те, что кратные 500 - это 500 и 1000. Не могу понять как это записать в условие. Я только написал условие для того, чтобы найти сколько чисел от 1 до 1000 будут кратными 5, а как указать еще условие с кратными 100 и 500 не знаю

Comment: Ну вы напишите все условия кратности, а потом оптимизируйте избыточные места

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что именно нужно сделать. Посчитать количество таких високосных лет? Само условие високосности вот:

```js
function isLeapYear (year) {
  if ( (year % 5 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0) || (year % 100 === 0 && year % 500 === 0) ) return true;
  return false;
}

console.log( isLeapYear(1) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(3) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(5) ); // true
console.log( isLeapYear(55) ); // true
console.log( isLeapYear(100) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(200) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(300) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(400) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(500) ); // true
console.log( isLeapYear(600) ); // false
console.log( isLeapYear(1000) ); // true
```

Comment: Ваш ответ мне нравится больше всего и я за него проголосую. Но я бы сохранил результат `year % 100 === 0` в отдельную переменную, для маленьких чисел это не будет играть роли, но для огромных чисел, повторный пересчёт займёт заметно больше времени, особенно, если используется эта проверка во многих местах

Comment: А вообще я тут подумал, после `логического или` проверку на `year % 100 === 0` можно просто убрать

Answer (score 0):

Вот что я придумал, надеюсь это вам поможет ^-^

```js
var countYear = [];
countYear['multipleOfFive '] = 0;
countYear['multipleOfHundred '] = 0;
countYear['multipleOfFiveHundred '] = 0;
let i = 5;
while (i <= 1000) {
  if (i % 500 == 0) {
    countYear['multipleOfFiveHundred']++;
  }

  if (i % 100 == 0) {
    countYear['multipleOfHundred']++;
  }

  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    countYear['multipleOfFive']++;
  }
  i += 5;
}
console.log(countYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное это точно было нужно

```
 const multiple = (n, maxCount) => {
  const century = 100; // Век
  let fullCount = 0; // Кол-во високосных годов за 1000 лет
  let centuryCount = 0; // Кол-во високосных годов за 100 лет
  let maxCenturyCount = 0; // Кол-во високосных веков
  let result;
  for (let i = 1; i < maxCount + 1; i++) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      fullCount++;
    }
  }
  for (let i = 1; i < century + 1; i++) {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      centuryCount++;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 1; i < maxCount + 1; i++) {
    if (i % (n * century) === 0) {
      maxCenturyCount++;
    }
  }

  result = `Кол-во високосных годов за 1000 лет - ${fullCount
    }\nКол-во високосных годов за 100 лет - ${centuryCount}\nКол-во високосных веков = ${maxCenturyCount}`;

  return result;
}

multiple(5, 1000);
```